# Why does duplicate node name happen here (in Keras)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a function like this to create a mask (from a relaxed bernoulli distribution).

```
# Using tensorflow 2.0.0, keras 2.3.1

def get_mask(inputs, units, px, ph):
    input_shape = K.shape(inputs)
    B = input_shape[0]
    D = input_shape[2]
    t = 1e-1
    eps = K.epsilon()

    ux = K.random_uniform((4, B, D))
    uh = K.random_uniform((4, B, units))

    zx = (1-K.sigmoid((K.log(px+eps) - K.log(1-px+eps) + K.log(ux+eps) - K.log(1-ux+eps)) / t))/(1-px)
    zh = (1-K.sigmoid((K.log(ph+eps) - K.log(1-ph+eps) + K.log(uh+eps) - K.log(1-uh+eps)) / t))/(1-ph)

    return zx, xh
```

In the second line where I draw samples from uniform distribution `ValueError: Duplicate node name in graph: 'time_distributed_29/random_uniform/shape'`.

Why does it construct node name in such a way, and how can I avoid this?

I tried creating some other tensors from K.random_uniform before that, like `K.random_uniform((1, 2, 3))`, but they did not cause this problem.

Comment: Update, I switch from using `keras.backend` to using `tensorflow.keras.backend`. Is there any problem when using mixed keras?

Comment: yes, you should never mix tf.keras and keras, they are not the same library

Comment: @Khanetor, can you please confirm if your issue is resolved by switching from `keras.backend ` to `tensorflow.keras.backend`?

Comment: It is resolved by switching to `tensorflow.keras.backend` for now, in a sense that no error is thrown. I don't know if it has any consequence down the line.

Comment: @Khanetor, If switching to `tensorflow.keras.backend` has resolved your issue, is it not a good idea to convert everything into `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`, to avoid mixed usage. Also, you can try upgrading to Tensorflow Version `2.2`. Thanks!

Comment: I would love to switch everything to `tensorflow.keras.backend`, but I am developing a component of a much bigger project where they use `keras.backend` everywhere. It is impossible for me to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the Solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the benefit of the Community.

The error, `ValueError: Duplicate node name in graph: 'time_distributed_29/random_uniform/shape'` is resolved by replacing `keras.backend` with `tensorflow.keras.backend`.

Also, in this case, replacing `keras` with `tensorflow.keras` at every place will be a good practice.

Will update this Answer in case new information becomes available.

Happy Learning!